# Set gives an unexpected error message (Set::partw)

Tags: warning-messages, expression-manipulation

Here is a minimal example:

```
s = 1 /(a + b[3]) + 1 /(2 a + b[3]);
s[[1]] = Sum[s[[1]] /. b[3] -> k, {k, 3}]
s[[4]]
s[[4]] = Sum[s[[4]] /. b[3] -> k, {k, 3}]
```

Output:

```
Out[143]= 1/(1 + a) + 1/(2 + a) + 1/(3 + a)
Out[144]= 1/(2 a + b[3])
```

> Set::partw: Part 4 of (1/(1+a)+1/(2+a)+1/(3+a))+1/(2 a+b[3]) does not exist. >>

```
Out[145]= 1/(1 + 2 a) + 1/(2 + 2 a) + 1/(3 + 2 a)
```

I could only make the error occur when using `Set`. As the above code shows, both `s[[4]]` and `Sum[s[[4]] /. b[3] -> k, {k, 3}]` are well defined.

I have been struggling with similar errors for days, can someone please explain exactly what is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: Use `ReplacePart[s, 4 -> Sum[s[[4]] /. b[3] -> k, {k, 3}]]`

Comment: If you evaluate `s=s` before evaluating `s[[4]] = Sum[s[[4]] /. b[3] -> k, {k, 3}]`, the problem disappears

Comment: Thanks @rasher, there are a few different workarounds. However they are not optimal and do not behave the same as `Part`. For ex: `ReplaceParts[s,{}-> x]` returns `s` unaltered.

Comment: Hi @andre, wow `s=s` does work, but why!? Thanks

Comment: @ArturGower: Well, yes. `ReplacePart` is a function, so you need to assign the result, as in `s=ReplacePart...`. I *think* your issue is just an interesting gotcha - `part ([[]])` works on fullform expressions, and `s` vs `s=s` (which I noted when trying your code) gives the exact same fullform result. Beats me, perhaps L.S. or M.W. or other wizards will chime in. In any case, IMHO `ReplacePart` is the way to go working with expressions.

Answer (score 3):

The reason this error occurs is because `Set` and `Part` have the Attribute `HoldFirst`, while functions like `Position`, which was used to get the position 4, does not have `HoldFirst`.

To verify, the line

```
s[[1]] = Sum[s[[1]] /. b[3] -> k, {k, 3}]
```

adds a parenthesis which does not get evaluated, so

```
(s//Hold)[[1,4]]
Out[1] = Part::partw: "Part 4 of (1/(1+a)+1/(2+a)+1/(3+a))+1/(2\a+b[3]) does not exist."
```

where as using `Evaluate` will distribute the parenthesis (effectively distributing the function `Plus`)

```
(s//Evaluate //Hold)[[1,4]]
1/(2 a + b[3])
```

So as pointed out by @andre executing `s=s` before `s[[4]]= ...` would solve the problem.

I thank @andre and @rasher for their contributions.

Comment: +1 for the analysis - I thought it might be a hold, but was working on answering the bit-flip question elsewhere. Thanks for following up, it's a good example.

Comment: You are right : `s[[1]] = Sum[s[[1]] /. b[3] -> k, {k, 3}]` adds a parenthesis which does *not get evaluated*. This can be seen if you evaluate `Trace[s]` : you see transformation of s from a 2 elements expression (with parenthesis) to a 4 elements expression.